# R: Rounding only if there are more than two decimal places

Tags: r, rounding

I am looking to round a set of values to the nearest whole number, but only if the number has two or more decimal places. Otherwise, I want to keep the number unchanged.

It can be done using `gsubfn`, a regex and multiple type transformations, but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

```
library(gsubfn)

y <- c(210.61233,212.41, 213.2, 214)

y <- as.character(y)
as.numeric(gsubfn("(\\d+\\.\\d{2,})", ~ round(as.numeric(x), 0) ,  y))
#211.0 212.0 213.2 214.0
```

Comment: You can test whether `10*x == floor(10*x)`. If not, `x` has more than one decimal/

Comment: Could you explain why it matters? I guess these values are to be shown to an user, but is it such embarrassing to show those decimals?

Comment: The values are from two different sources, one of which the end-user is used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is this:

```
y <- c(210.61233,212.41, 213.2, 214)

ifelse(y == round(y, 1), y, round(y))
[1] 211.0 212.0 213.2 214.0
```

First you check if a number changes if rounded to one digit. If not you keep it, otherwise you round it to the nearest whole number.

Answer (score 2):

This is arguably overly complicating but one could write up a simple function as follows:

```
y <- c(210.61233,212.41, 213.2, 214)


round_if<-function(my_vec,min_length){

my_pattern<-paste0("\\.(?=\\d{",min_length,",})")

to_replace<-grep(my_pattern,my_vec,perl=TRUE)

    my_vec[to_replace] <- round(Filter(function(x)grep(my_pattern,
                                   x,perl = TRUE),my_vec),0)
    my_vec

  }
```

Testing it on the above:

```
  round_if(y,2)
#[1] 211.0 212.0 213.2 214.0
```